# Link Deployment status to workitems in TFS

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, tfs

I am new to Tfs or Azure DevOps and I am trying to link deployment status of my releases to work items. I have tried going to classic release pipelines -> options -> integrations -> Report Deployment status to boards and have mapped the environments.

[image]

But I want to link these deployments only when the deployment is done through Master branch or a branch that starts with "Release" and not from other brances. I don't see any option in pipelines to select a specific branch.

Currently deployment status of all branches are being displayed in deployment section of workItems which is making it hard to follow the deployments we care about.
[image]

I have tried looking into documentation but I couldn't find anything that helps. I am sure there must be some way to achieve this.

Any help is appreciated.